# Where is the XML Editor source code

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xml-editor

I am using the Eclipse which version as following:

---

**Eclipse   Java EE   IDE   for   Web   Developers.**

```
Version:   Indigo   Service   Release   1 
Build id:   20110916-0149
```

---

It includes an XML Editor plugin, my question is: Where is the source code for the XML Editor?
 Can anybody give me an URL for getting the source code of the XML Editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you have a question about where the source for a plugin is in Eclipse, you can use a little known hidden feature in Eclipse called the **Plugin Spy**.

Put your cursor focus on whatever you are interested in inside Eclipse and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

In the case of the XML Editor the result looks like the image below.  As you can see, the plugin is `org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui`, and it even gives you the class to start with (`XMLMultiPageEditorPart`).

There is some great additional detail on finding and working with Eclipse source here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#swt_spy

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the support for CVS is/will be stopped.
You could also get access to the source by using Git.

1. For Git access, you need a user account: https://dev.eclipse.org/site_login/createaccount.php
2. You need the right URL to "clone" the repository: http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git

Comment: The URLs for other plugins you can search here:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to check out the source code.  It is available in a cvs repository here:

```
:pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/webtools
```

In the `/sourceediting/plugins/` directory, check out the following plugins:

1. org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui
2. org.eclipse.wst.xml.core
3. org.eclipse.wst.sse.core
4. org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui

The first two contain code specific to the xml support, and the second two projects contain general structured text editing code.